# Apache FOP and Excel

Tags: excel, apache-fop

I ask for help with the next task. It is planned to use Apache FOP to generate various reports, but the question arose whether FOP can generate any format that could be opened in Excel. It is desirable with an example. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How come you choose fop to generate something for excel? fop usually is used to generate PDF. You could use xslt to transform xmls into xmls that could be opened by excel. xslt while being considered part of a typical xsl-fo workflow can be used without fop, e.g. in the form of [xalan from apache](https://xalan.apache.org/). An example can hardly be given because you don't specify at all what your input is.

Comment: @Stefan Hegny The management chose FOP to create an alternative means of printing documents. The current printing system creates a pcl file that is fed directly to the printer. Such a system has a number of drawbacks, so it was decided to develop an alternative printing system, for which FOP was chosen, output to excel is not a key element, but it would be great to have such functionality.

Comment: what is your input? FOP for printing is a valid choice. Generate an xml for excel is a different task but can be done with xslt / xalan (xalanj being shipped as part of apache fop)

Comment: @Stefan Hegny Information comes from the OpenEdge Progress database on Sles, accordingly the input goes the most diverse, from printing checks to generating reports. I am tasked with repeating the old functionality, it is possible to expand it with FOP, and I was also told that it would not be bad to be able to open some reports in excel for their possible adjustment. More I can not yet say, because I'm studying the current functional and I find a way to solve the task.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly let me  know your input file format?. If your file is Xml format or .fo format we can extract the excel file  using the input file by using with combination apache poi. we can extract the output files in XLS or XLSX format . Else  combine open office XML to apache fop code. where it takes alot of effort.